# How to get an existing MediaContainerModel in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I tried to get `MediaFormatModel, MediaModel, MediaFolderModel` etc with the help of `MediaService` but only the `MediaContainer` is not possible to get from `MediaService` and I tried with `ModelService`. Only one possibility I found that by getting `MediaModel` we can get the `MediaContainerModel` but I need to get specific `MediaContainerModel` by passing qualifier. Like for example:

```
final MediaModel mm1 = mediaService.getMedia(catalogVersion, "picture515x515");
final MediaFormatModel mf1200 = mediaService.getFormat("1200x1200");
final MediaFolderModel mfm = mediaService.getFolder("convertedimages");
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution we can get as follows

@Autowired
    MediaContainerService mediaContainerService;
......
MediaContainerModel mediaContainer = null;
            try
            {
                mediaContainer = 
mediaContainerService.getMediaContainerForQualifier("testContainer");
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                mediaContainer = createMediaContainer("testContainer");
            }
            mediaContainer.setCatalogVersion(catalogVersion);

Comment: I would recommend against catching general exceptions: for instance this code will throw: "AmbiguousIdentifierException" if you sync your container to an other catalog version (since it will find two media containers with that qualifier, because you did not specify a catalog version). The exception you are looking for would be: UnknownIdentifierException"

Comment: Yes, you are right thijsraets. Here I am getting the active catalogversion. so that it will be only one at  a time. 
  final CatalogVersionModel catalogVersion = catalogService.getCatalogForId("electronicsContentCatalog").getActiveCatalogVersion();

Answer (score 1):

You can always retrieve models using the *flexiblesearh getModelByExample*

```
CatalogVersionModel catalogVersion = catalogVersionService.getCatalogVersion("yourCatalogName", "version");

MediaContainerModel container = new MediaContainerModel();
container.setCatalogVersion(catalogVersion);
container.setQualifier("yourQualifier");
try
{
    container = flexibleSearchService.getModelByExample(container);
}//no container found
catch (final ModelNotFoundException ex)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     private MediaContainerModel getExistingMediaContainer(CatalogVersionModel catalogVersion, String qualifier) {
    final String query = "SELECT {" + MediaContainerModel.PK + "} FROM {" + MediaContainerModel._TYPECODE + "} "
            + "WHERE {" + MediaContainerModel.QUALIFIER + "} = ?qualifier AND " + "{" + MediaContainerModel.CATALOGVERSION + "} = ?catalogVersion";
    final FlexibleSearchQuery fQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
    fQuery.addQueryParameter("qualifier", qualifier);
    fQuery.addQueryParameter("catalogVersion", catalogVersion);
    final SearchResult<MediaContainerModel> searchResult = flexibleSearchService.search(fQuery);
    if (searchResult.getTotalCount() > 0) {
        return searchResult.getResult().get(0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```